# Сочетание использования float (для изображения) и column layout для текста

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Столкнулся со сложностью совместного использования float и column.
Есть объект с обтеканием. Текст его прекрасно обтекает.
[image: пример 1]

Но как только я начинаю использовать разделение на колонки , обтекание пропадает
[image: пример2]

Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы эти свойства работали одновременно? То бишь если текста много, то появляются 2 колонки слева от карты и 2 колонки под картой.

Фрагмент кода [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfxyonzh/1/).

```css
#map {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  background: #f00;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#text {
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 30px;
  -moz-column-gap: 30px;
  column-gap: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="text">
  В наследство музею достались главный дом, флигели, каретник, службы с конюшней, ледник и школа для де­вочек. Не повезло малым архитектурным фор­мам парка и амбарам, утраченным к нашим дням. Усадебному комплексу был придан ста­тус памятника федерального
  значения. Многолетние натурные, архитектурные ис­следования, инженерно-технологические, историко-архивные, дендрологические и биологи­ческие изыскания, проведённые большим ав­торским коллективом, воссоздали картину формирования архитектурно-паркового
  ан­самбля '. Сохранились планы строений и пар­ка, воспоминания современников, фотографии зелёных зон усадьбы и интерьеров домов, сде­ланные владельцами в 1890-х годах и дошедшие до наших дней благодаря их потом­кам. В результате об­ширных многолетних
  исследований был со­здан генеральный план усадьбы, появились проекты реставрации архитектурных памят­ников и парковой зо­ны, позволившие в 1989 году начать реставрационные рабо­ты, а десятилетие спу­стя — развернуть ме­мориальные экспозиции для приёма
  посетите­лей в главном доме усадьбы, флигелях и служ­бах с конюшней. Совершенно полная реставрация усадебного комплекса невозможна. В наследство музею достались главный дом, флигели, каретник, службы с конюшней, ледник и школа для де­вочек. Не повезло
  малым архитектурным фор­мам парка и амбарам, утраченным к нашим дням. Усадебному комплексу был придан ста­тус памятника федерального значения. Многолетние натурные, архитектурные ис­следования, инженерно-технологические, историко-архивные, дендрологические
  и биологи­ческие изыскания, проведённые большим ав­торским коллективом, воссоздали картину формирования архитектурно-паркового ан­самбля '. Сохранились планы строений и пар­ка, воспоминания современников, фотографии зелёных зон усадьбы и интерьеров
  домов, сде­ланные владельцами в 1890-х годах и дошедшие до наших дней благодаря их потом­кам. В результате об­ширных многолетних исследований был со­здан генеральный план усадьбы, появились проекты реставрации архитектурных памят­ников и парковой зо­ны,
  позволившие в 1989 году начать реставрационные рабо­ты, а десятилетие спу­стя — развернуть ме­мориальные экспозиции для приёма посетите­лей в главном доме усадьбы, флигелях и служ­бах с конюшней. Совершенно полная реставрация усадебного комплекса невозможна.
</div>
```

Comment: Это вообще возможно?

Comment: приведите пример Вашего кода.

Comment: @Dmitriy, https://jsfiddle.net/nfxyonzh/1/

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

Возможный вариант решения нечто вроде https://jsfiddle.net/d_sem/Lh8cj8wc/

```
<div id="text">ваш текст <div id="map"></div> ваш текст</div>
```

Подробнее https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/ (см Example X)

Comment: Извините, но это совсем не то, что хотелось бы.

Comment: Грубо говоря, я хотел бы сделать текст в 4 колонки, но чтобы у третьей и 4-ой колонок был вертикальный margin размером с карту

Comment: @Ivan Честно говоря не понимаю, чем вам не подходит это решение.

Comment: @vadim, структурно не подходит. У меня контент генерируется CMS-кой и эти блоки находятся рядом в DOM. Соответственно, решение, где один блок в другом, для меня не совсем подходит. Более того, если я разобью текст на 4 колонки, как говорилось в вопросе, картинка станет размером в одну колонку, а нужно было в 2.